# Как сделать выборку из XML через PHP?

Tags: xml, php

Есть xml http://www.bsuir.by/psched/rest/222404

Нужно например те subject где weekDay="ср"

То что имеем сейчас:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.bsuir.by/psched/rest/222404");
foreach ($xml->ROW as $subject) {
echo '<p>'.$subject['subject'].' '.$subject['auditorium'].' '.$subject['teacher'].'</p>';
}
```

Результат выполнения: http://zb-group.us/tests/bsuirrasp/date.php

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать [PHPQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Basics)